# C# - equality operator with list of interface type not working as expected

Tags: c#, collections, operators, equals, equality

Consider the following code, where `ClassOne` is a class derived from `IClass`:

```
List<IClass> list = new List<IClass>();
list.Add(new ClassOne("foo", "bar"));
list.Add(new ClassOne("baz", "bam"));

List<IClass> list2 = new List<IClass>();
list2.Add(new ClassOne("foo", "bar"));
list2.Add(new ClassOne("baz", "bam"));

if (list == list2)
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are equal.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are NOT equal.");
```

The equality operator returns false (i.e. lists do not match), besides the fact the the `operator ==`, `operator !=`, `Equals(ClassOne)`, `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` have been implemented/overridden for `ClassOne`. Why is that? I would expect the equality operator to return true. Are there any other methods/interfaces that must be implemented for the `==` operator to work as expected?

For reference, here's the implementation of `ClassOne` and `IClass`:

```
public interface IClass
{
    string getA();
    string getB();
} //interface


public class ClassOne : IClass, IEquatable<ClassOne>
{
    public ClassOne(string a, string b)
    {
        strA = a;
        strB = b;
    }

    public string getA()
    {
        return strA;
    }

    public string getB()
    {
        return strB;
    }

    public bool Equals(ClassOne other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (!string.Equals(strA, other.strA))
            return false;
        return string.Equals(strB, other.strB);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (other is ClassOne)
        {
            ClassOne c1 = (ClassOne)other;
            return Equals(c1);
        }
        //not ClassOne, so it is not equal
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hc_a = -1;
        if (null != strA)
            hc_a = strA.GetHashCode();
        int hc_b = -1;
        if (null != strB)
            hc_b = strB.GetHashCode();
        return hc_a ^ hc_b;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ClassOne left, ClassOne right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null) || ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return false;
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ClassOne left, ClassOne right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    private string strA, strB;
} //class
```

Any help or hints in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is that? I would expect the equality operator to return true.

Not correct - the `==` operator (and `Equals()`) are not defined on `List<T>` to check the equality of its contents - it defaults to reference equality from the operator defined on `object`.  Since the two lists are different objects, `==` returns false.

You can use the Linq [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method to determine if two lists contain equal objects in the same order:

```
if (list.SequenceEqual(list2))
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are equal.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are NOT equal.");
```

Comment: That's bad. So I have to use `list.Equals(list2)` whenever I want to check the contents of the lists for equality?

Comment: Nope.  `Equals` is not overridden either.  You'd need to use `SequenceEquals` from Linq or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `==` operator is not overloaded for the `List<T>` class. `==` for lists is simply reference equality. Even two `List<int>` objects that hold the same `int`s are not equal, etc.

If you ask whether `list == list2`, the compiler will call the `==` operator for `List<T>`, and the designer of the `List<T>` class have decided that two lists are only equal if both refer to the same list. In other words:

```
public class List<T> {

    public static bool operator ==(List<T> left, List<T> right) {
        return ReferenceEquals(left, right);
    }

}
```

(Evidently there is more content in the `List<T>` class, and since it uses reference equality, one does *not* have to overload the operator).

Comment: Well, `List<T>` does not define the operator at all, so the operator on `object` is used.  While your example illustrates that, the code is not actually written that way.

Comment: @DStanley: between brackets I say that: you indeed do not have to overload the operator. It is simply to show *explicitly* why `List<T>` does not check elementwise equality.